# Odoo8 - generate report from Python by given user and data range

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I need to generate timesheets report for a given user in a given data range.
And I also need to sum the timesheets hours by date so each row in the report has unique date.

I have simple report ready as well as wizard for picking particular user and dates.

But I'm having trouble with actually generating report in Python and passing data to the report. When I click the print button on my wizard I get this error:

```
ProgrammingError: relation "hr_timesheet_karty_wizard" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "hr_timesheet_karty_wizard" ("id", "date_from", ...
```

What I'm doing wrong?
I'm not really sure what to do with `records`. Should I put them in 'doc_ids' or 'docs'?
How to sum the records by dates?

I'm using Odoo 8.

Here is my python code:

```py
# __init__.py

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from . import wizard
```

```py
# wizard/__init__.py

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from . import wizard_karty
```

```py
# wizard/wizard_karty.py

from openerp import api, models, fields
from datetime import datetime

class hr_timesheet_karty_wizard(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'hr.timesheet.karty.wizard'

    employee_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="hr.employee", required=True)
    date_from = fields.Date(default=fields.Datetime.now, required=True)
    date_to = fields.Date(default=fields.Datetime.now, required=True)

    @api.multi
    def print_report(self, data=None):

        records = self.env['hr.analytic.timesheet'].search([('employee_id', '=', self.employee_id),('date_from', '>=', self.date_from),('date_to', '<=', self.date_to)])   
        # sum records hours if date is the same (group by date)

        report_obj = self.env['report']
        report = report_obj._get_report_from_name('hr_timesheet_karty.template_hr_timesheet_karty')
        docargs = {
            'doc_ids': self._ids,
            'doc_model': report.model,
            'docs': records,
        }
        return report_obj.render('hr_timesheet_karty.template_hr_timesheet_karty', docargs)
```

Here is my wizard:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
  <data>

    <record id="view_hr_timesheet_karty_wizard" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">hr.timesheet.karty.wizard.form</field>
        <field name="model">hr.timesheet.karty.wizard</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Leaves by Department">
            <group>
                <field name="employee_id"/>
                <field name="date_from"/>
                <field name="date_to"/>
            </group>
            <footer>
                <button name="print_report" string="Print" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/> or
                <button string="Cancel" special="cancel" class="oe_link"/>
            </footer>
        </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="action_hr_timesheet_karty_wizard" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Time sheet report</field>
        <field name="res_model">hr.timesheet.karty.wizard</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="view_hr_timesheet_karty_wizard"/>
        <field name="target">new</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem id="menu_hr_timesheet_karty_wizard"
        name="Time sheet report"
        parent="hr.menu_hr_reporting_timesheet"
        action="action_hr_timesheet_karty_wizard"
        sequence="1"
        icon="STOCK_PRINT"/>

  </data>
</openerp>
```

And here is my report:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
  <data>
    <report
        id="action_hr_timesheet_karty"
        string="Time sheet report"
        model="hr.analytic.timesheet"
        report_type="qweb-pdf"
        name="hr_timesheet_karty.template_report_hr_timesheet_karty"
    />

    <template id="template_hr_timesheet_karty">
        <t t-call="report.html_container">
            <t t-call="report.external_layout">
                <div class="page">

                    <table class="table table-condensed">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>User</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Time</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                                <td><span t-field="o.user_id.name"/></td>
                                <td><span t-field="o.date"/></td>
                                <td class="text-right"><span t-field="o.unit_amount"/> h</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>

            </t>
        </t>
    </template>

  </data>
</openerp>
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstract Model super-class for creating an abstract class meant to be inherited by regular models (Models or TransientModels) **but not meant to be usable on its own or persisted**.

- `_auto = False` *# don't create any database backend for AbstractModels*
- `_register = False` # *not visible in ORM registry, meant to be python-inherited only*

`TransientModel` is used for temporary data, stored in the database but automatically vacuumed every so often.

You need to use `TransientModel` instead of `AbstractModel`.

```
class hr_timesheet_karty_wizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'hr.timesheet.karty.wizard'
```

The `print_report` method looks like the `render_html` method of qweb report parser.

- Change `print_report` to :

  ```
  @api.multi
  def print_report(self):
      self.ensure_one()
      datas = {'wizard_id': self.id}
      return self.env['report'].get_action(self, 'hr_timesheet_karty.template_hr_timesheet_karty', data=datas)
  ```
- Add a report parser:

  ```
  class HrTimesheetKartyReport(models.AbstractModel):
      _name = 'report.hr_timesheet_karty.template_hr_timesheet_karty'

      @api.multi
      def render_html(self, data=None):
          hr_analytic_timesheet = self.env['hr.analytic.timesheet']
          if data and 'wizard_id' in data:
              wizard = self.env['hr.timesheet.karty.wizard'].browse(data['wizard_id'])
              records = hr_analytic_timesheet.search([('employee_id', '=', wizard.employee_id.id),
                                                      ('date_from', '>=', wizard.date_from),
                                                      ('date_to', '<=', wizard.date_to)])
          else:
              records = hr_analytic_timesheet.browse(self._ids)
          # sum records hours if date is the same (group by date)

          report_obj = self.env['report']
          report = report_obj._get_report_from_name('hr_timesheet_karty.template_hr_timesheet_karty')
          docargs = {
              'doc_ids': self._ids,
              'doc_model': report.model,
              'docs': records,
          }
          return report_obj.render('hr_timesheet_karty.template_hr_timesheet_karty', docargs)
  ```
- Change report action name and template id to `hr_timesheet_karty.template_hr_timesheet_karty`.

  ```
  <report
      id="action_hr_timesheet_karty"
      string="Time sheet report"
      model="hr.analytic.timesheet"
      report_type="qweb-pdf"
      name="hr_timesheet_karty.template_hr_timesheet_karty"
  />

  <template id="template_hr_timesheet_karty">
  ```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213781/discussion-on-answer-by-kenly-odoo8-generate-report-from-python-by-given-user).

Answer (score 1):

That error message tells that you don't have a table for your wizard in your database. Even if it is an abstract model it should have one.

Do you import your Python code in `__init__.py` -file?

Comment: Yes I do. I edited my question to include `__init__.py` as well. I have to add this table to database manually? In previous custom modules it was created automatically... Also what is the difference between `Transient` and `Abstract` models? I've seen both in similar cases and I don't know which one should I use.

Comment: Just as Kenly explains on another answer, answer is no. You never modify your database manually when creating modules in Odoo. ORM takes care of it.